# Confidence interval about a multivariate normal probability

Tags: confidence-interval, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

From a given sample $x_i \underset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim} {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ it is possible to get a confidence interval about the probability $\Pr(x_i \geq a)$ for any number $a$, by "inverting" some tolerance intervals.

If ${\boldsymbol x}_i \underset{\mathrm{iid}}{\sim}{\cal N}_p({\boldsymbol \mu}, \Sigma)$ is a sample from a $p$-variate normal distribution, how to get a confidence interval about the probability $\Pr(x_{i1} \geq a_1, \ldots, x_{ip} \geq a_p)$? It is easy to get a credible interval in the Bayesian framework, but what about frequentist methods? Is the bootstrap asymptotically valid? Does there exist another known approach?

**EDIT 15/09/2012:** The Delta method should be possible. If someone is comfortable with the calculations I would be glad if he posts the solution here ;)

Comment: There's something strange about the notation: given that $(x_i)$ is the sample, then $\Pr(x_i \ge a)$ makes no sense (or is trivially $0$ or $1$). E.g., if the sample is $(3.12, -1.03, 0.17)$, $i=3$, and $a=1$, this expression means nothing other than $\Pr(0.17 \ge 1)$.  This makes it difficult to discern what the question is asking.

Comment: @whuber Stephane is using small x to denote a random variable contrary to our custom to use small letters for observaed values and capitals for random variables.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael, but I still cannot make sense of that interpretation. If the tolerance interval is constructed from the $x_i$, it estimates a property of the distribution, not a probability; if it is actually a prediction interval, then it estimates the probability for an independent result not included within the $x_i$. There's a lot of ambiguity here.

Comment: @whuber Michael is right, I'm using some abusive notations, but I think they are not ambiguous if the reader uses "psychology" to guess my statement (by droping trivial or meaningless possibilities). Such abusive notations are common in the Bayesian literature, I think.

Comment: @whuber The probability $\Pr(X_i \geq a)$ is a function of $\theta$. Estimating $\theta$ straightforwardly yields an estimate of this probability. And it is possible to use one-sided tolerance intervals to get a confidence interval about this probability (recall that one-sided tolerance intervals are nothing but confidence intervals about a percentile). Isn't it clear ?

Comment: Thank you, Stéphane: it is now much clearer after your explanation.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Yes when you put it that way.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I may be missing your point, but I don't see why you need to think about $({\boldsymbol \mu}, \Sigma)$ at all to give a confidence interval for the probability you want (call it $p$). Regardless of the distribution of $x_i$, you can define the random variable $$z_i = \mathcal{I}\{ x_{i1} \geq a_1, \ldots, x_{ip} \geq a_p \}$$ Then $z_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} {\rm Bernoulli}(p)$ and you can do inference about $p$ the same way you normally would.

Comment: @Macro In the univariate case I think this method yields very larger confidence intervals than those based on tolerance intervals

Answer (score -1):

It is easier to construct confidence ellipsoids for multidimensional normals.  The probabilities you want require messy numerical integration, I think, since the regions are open-sided rectangular.  I think you could certainly bootstrap the samples and get bootstrap estimates of the joint probabilities.  But I think that would not be commonly done since there is an exact answer even though it involves multidimensional numerical integration.

Comment: I don't understand how to derive the confidence interval about the probability of a "rectangle" from a confidence ellipsoid (even with integration) ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I am not saying that.  I am just saying that for multivariate normal distributions it is easy to calulate ingegrals for elliptical regions but difficult for rectangular ones.